# Music for noir combat scenes

Tags: gm-techniques, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, music

Right now planning noir style VtM campaign which would have place in 1940s and I'm trying to make it more atmospheric for my players. We're playing via Roll20, so music means a lot.

The problem I faced: I have no ideas about what music would be best fitting for combat scenes. It's too early for some agressive rock or electronic music. All jazz is too slow or too cheerful for intense scenes. And it looks like for this period dark fantasy music wouldn't fit at all too.

May be you have any ideas about music generes I can use? :)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Check out our [tour] here to see how we work. I've closed this question since in general we don't recommend music for games, since it's primarily a matter of opinion -- and a matter of *quite vast* opinion that our site isn't suited to handle. Instead we're focused on questions that can have a single best or correct answer, and music being largely a personal choice means we can't really advise on that. However you can instead [ask this question on a forum, such as one of the ones we've made a list of here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449).